# Do we have anything like GTMetrix for Mobile Apps?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-test, gtmetrix

I have a flutter app for android and iOS (dealsfidners). People say it takes some time to load during a mobile internet connection without wifi. For websites, I  used to do a performance baseline with GTMetrix and improve something and verify if my performance improved or not. But I don't know how do I measure the mobile app performance after my changes in the code whether it got improved or not. Do we have anything like GTMetrix tool for mobile apps to record baseline performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter has its own profiler:

```
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/network
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/cpu-profiler
```